# DeepPavlov elmo is too slow

Tags: python, deep-learning, nlp, word-embedding

I tried to use ELMO embeddings (ElmoEmbedder) from DeepPavlov library. It works really slow, 64 second per 100 senteces.

I tried to increase mini_batch_size, but it didn't speed up algorithm.

Is it possible to speed up ElmoEmbedder?

Answer (score 5):

`mini_batch_size` might have a significant impact on the performance only when yor run the model on GPU.

In case you don't have GPU try to use [Google Colab](https://colab.research.google.com/). It provides you with free access to GPU and TPU.

```
!pip install deeppavlov

from deeppavlov.deep import find_config
from deeppavlov.core.commands.infer import build_model
config_path = find_config('elmo_ru-wiki')
model = build_model(config_path, load_trained = True, download = True)
a = model(data)
```

Do not forget to enable GPU in `Edit->Notebook settings->Hardware accelerator`